# How to assign the value to local variable in query its self?

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to assign the value of local variable through Postgres SQL for example 
 Param is my local variable;
 I want to assign the count value of the column from the query without using the data set to param.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set constants before your query with the DO command:

DO $$

```
DECLARE myvar integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT 5 INTO myvar;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table;
    CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS
    SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE   id = myvar;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```